# Create vim tags like the user manual

Tags: vim

I want to make tags between .txt files in a way that's similar to the vim user manual.

I'm already aware of how to generate a tags file and I can link between my files. The only thing I want to figure out is how to make all of my tags a different color (like blue in the user manual) so they are easy to identify.

My best guess is that I'd have to customize syntax highlighting for a txt file, but I'm not sure how it would distinguish between tags and normal text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracting tags and their links is the one thing; you seem to have solved that part.

To recognize and highlight the tags, you need syntax rules. If your tags style follows the Vim help, tag definitions are surrounded by `*` characters, and tag links by `|` characters.

The following excerpt from `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/help.vim` covers this:

```
syn match helpHyperTextJump "\\\@<!|[#-)!+-~]\+|" contains=helpBar
syn match helpHyperTextEntry    "\*[#-)!+-~]\+\*\s"he=e-1 contains=helpStar
syn match helpHyperTextEntry    "\*[#-)!+-~]\+\*$" contains=helpStar

hi def link helpHyperTextJump   Subtitle
hi def link helpHyperTextEntry  String
```

If you put that (optimally after replacing `help...` with `txt...`) into a custom `~/.vim/syntax/txt.vim` syntax script, you can activate your syntax with `:setf txt` (or even automate this via a custom *filetype detection*).

Comment: It might be simpler to `:set syntax=help`.  You can automate this with autocommands or modelines.  See `:help 'syntax'`, `:help autocommand`, and `:help modeline`.

Comment: That was simpler benjifisher. However, it was nice to see the big picture as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The help syntax defines many other highlightings as well. As long as you don't mind, that's indeed easier, but you're stuck with the whole syntax as it exists.

Comment: My final solution was to add txt files in    `.vim/ftdetect/txt.vim` and then add    `setlocal syntax=help` (amongst other things) in     `.vim/ftplugin/txt.vim.` That saved me from filling my `.vimrc` with autocommands.

Answer (score 0):

The tags in the manual are available through the `:help` command. You probably will not benefit from mixing your text files with Vim documentation.

If you intend to create links between your text files only, you could try some plugin write for this purpose; I'd recommend [the vimwiki plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2226) -- it includes several mappings for creating/managing links, list and headers on text files, which are correct highlighted through the syntax file included in it.

Some alternatives are [listed on vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=text+link&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search), as [utl.vim : Univeral Text Linking](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=293), [Txtfmt (The Vim Highlighter)](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2208) and [TxtBrowser : Browse plain text easily](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2899).

Comment: My intention is not to mix my files with the vim documentation, but rather to create a similar style where tagged items are simply highlighted blue. As I said, I've created the tags with no problem and can go through them using Ctrl-] and T. I was hoping this would be possible without a plugin as it exists in the documentation.